# Vetor de Struct: Passagem por referência em C

Tags: c, array, funções, struct, referência

Esse código é de um simples cadastro de pessoas, contendo código e nome da pessoa.
Estou confusa quanto a passagem do vetor de struct para o procedimento "inserir".

Ao compilar, o programa para de funcionar. No compilador tenho o seguinte erro: "Program received signal sigsegv segmentation fault". Vi que esse erro tem algo a ver com referência incorreta a um ponteiro, mas não sei como resolver.

Segue o código:

```js
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
struct pessoas
{
 int codigo;
 char nome [50];
};

 struct pessoas vetpessoas[5];
 int k = 0;


void inserir (struct pessoas *vetpessoas, int *k)
{
 char nomeaux [50];
 int codaux, i, j;
 char resp, resp1;
 
 resp = 's';
 
 if (*k > 0)
 {
  i = *k;
 }
 else 
 {
  i = 0;
 }
 
 do
 {
  do
  {
   printf ("Entre com o codigo:");
   scanf("%i",codaux);
  }
  while (codaux < 0);
  
  do
  {
   printf ("Entre com o nome:");
   scanf ("%s",nomeaux);
  }
  while (nomeaux == "");
  
  do
  {
   j = j+1;
  }
  while (codaux != vetpessoas[j].codigo && j<i);
  
  if (j==i)
  {
   do
   {
    printf("Confirma a inclusao (S/N) ?");
    scanf ("%s",resp1);
   }
   while (resp1!='s' || resp1!='n');
   
   if (resp1 =='s')
   {
    vetpessoas[i].codigo = codaux;
    strcpy(vetpessoas[i].nome, nomeaux);
    printf ("Inclusao efetuada com sucesso!");
   }
   else 
   {
    printf ("Codigo ja cadastrado!");
    i = i-1;
   }
  }
  
  if (i < 4)
  {
   do
   {
    printf("Deseja continuar incluindo (S/N) ?");
    scanf("%c",resp);
   }
   while (resp1!='s' || resp1!='n');
  }
  i = i+1;
 }
 while (resp=='s' && i<=4);
 
 *k = i;
 
 if (i > 4)
 {
  printf ("Vetor já está Cheio! Não é permitido mais armazenar valores!!!");
 }

}

main ()
{ 

    inserir (vetpessoas, &k);
 return 0;

}
```

Comment: Um dos problemas que vejo é que o código é confuso demais, parece ter várias coisas desnecessárias, o que facilita cometer erros. Tem algum motivo para fazer tudo isso ou é erro também?

Comment: Se você se refere aos "do while" é que o programa precisa verificar cada entrada de dados, isso acabou ficando extenso.

Comment: Não, me refiro a várias coisas, E essa verificação não é suficiente, ainda não pego outros erros possíveis. E comecei reescrever mas uma falha na internet fez eu perder e não quis fazer de novo, até porque pra arrumar mesmo mudaria tanto que descaracterizaria seu código, do jeito que está acho que vai aprender muita coisa do jeito errado, nem vale a pena mexer nele, me desculpe. Só pra ter uma ideia o meu código já está quase 1/3 do tamanho do seu.

Comment: Sim, ainda tem muita coisa que não está sendo validada. Na verdade o código é adaptado de um algoritmo que a professora passou. Imagino que sua versão esteja muito mais simplificada. Obrigada pela disposição em ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema do seu código é nas leituras: em scanf você deve passar o endereço de memória da variável que irá receber a leitura, e não a própria variável. Abaixo está o seu código com a correção.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
struct pessoas
{
    int codigo;
    char nome [50];
};

struct pessoas vetpessoas[5];
int k = 0;


void inserir (struct pessoas *vetpessoas, int *k)
{
    char nomeaux [50];
    int codaux, i, j;
    char resp, resp1;

    resp = 's';

    if (*k > 0)
    {
        i = *k;
    }
    else 
    {
        i = 0;
    }

    do
    {
        do
        {
            printf ("Entre com o codigo:");
            scanf("%i", &codaux);
        }
        while (codaux < 0);

        do
        {
            printf ("Entre com o nome:");
            scanf ("%s", &nomeaux);
        }
        while (nomeaux == "");

        do
        {
            j = j+1;
        }
        while (codaux != vetpessoas[j].codigo && j<i);

        if (j==i)
        {
            do
            {
                printf("Confirma a inclusao (S/N) ?");
                fflush(stdin);
                scanf ("%c", &resp1);

                if (resp1 == 's' || resp1 == 'n')
                    break;
            }
            while (1);

            if (resp1 =='s')
            {
                vetpessoas[i].codigo = codaux;
                strcpy(vetpessoas[i].nome, nomeaux);
                printf ("Inclusao efetuada com sucesso!");
            }
            else 
            {
                printf ("Codigo ja cadastrado!");
                i = i-1;
            }
        }

        if (i < 4)
        {
            do
            {
                fflush(stdin);
                printf("Deseja continuar incluindo (S/N) ?");
                scanf("%c", &resp);

                if (resp == 's' || resp == 'n')
                    break;
            }
            while (1);
        }
        i = i+1;
    }
    while (resp=='s' && i<=4);

    *k = i;

    if (i > 4)
    {
        printf ("Vetor já está Cheio! Não é permitido mais armazenar valores!!!");
    }

}

main ()
{   

    inserir (vetpessoas, &k);
    return 0;

}
```